# Return string instead of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, null

I'm using an API to get values to append to the DOM, out of the array a few of the values return `null` leaving them empty in the table. My question is it possible to return a string that states the "information is missing" instead of returning empty?

```
success: function(currency) {
    // loop through currency
    for (var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) {
        if (currency[i].currency == userCurrency) {
            var $tr = $("<tr />");
            $tr.append($("<td />").text(currency[i].volume));
            $tr.append($("<td />").text(currency[i].latest_trade));
            $tr.append($("<td />").text(currency[i].bid));
            $tr.append($("<td />").text(currency[i].high));
            $("#theTable tbody").append($tr);
        }
    }
}
});
});
});
```

Comment: try `.text(currency[i].bid || 'information is missing'));`

Answer (score 5):

use `|| "information is missing"` like so:-

```
$tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].volume || "information is missing"));
```

This will then use `"information is missing"` for any false value, ie: `0, null, undefined, "", false`.

Though if you only want to check for `null`, you could use an inline if:-

```
$tr.append( $("<td />").text(currency[i].volume != null ? currency[i].volume : "information is missing"));
```